# How to corp a picture into any shape via a template in android?

Tags: android, image, crop

I wanted to know if it was possible to crop a picture to any other shape not just square, rectangle or circle. 
Basically what I am looking for is that, the user can select a template of a png file (already present) and it cuts the picture in that shape.

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well it's definitely possible...just look at Whatsapp profile pictures

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ImageView imageViewPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_preview);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.this.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.source);
            final Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.this.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.mask);
            final Bitmap croppedBitmap = cropBitmap(source, mask);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imageViewPreview.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

private Bitmap cropBitmap(final Bitmap source, final Bitmap mask){
    final Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(croppedBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, null);
    final Paint maskPaint = new Paint();
    maskPaint.setXfermode(
            new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT));
    canvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, maskPaint);
    return croppedBitmap;
}
```

}

The main function is the "cropBitmap" function. Basically it receives two bitmaps, a source and a mask, and then it "crops" the source bitmap using the mask's shape.
This is my source bitmap:
[image: Source bitmap]
This is the mask bitmap:
[image: Mask bitmap]
And this is the result:
[image: Result]

Also, check out this great presentation, this might help you too: [Fun with Android shaders and filters](http://chiuki.github.io/android-shaders-filters/#/)