# Process ALPHA_8 bitmap in Android and show it in ImageView

Tags: java, android, image-processing, colors, bitmap

I'm implementing sobel edge detection algo. After processing I apply new pixel values, either 255 or 0. my problem is that the resulting bitmap is not showed in the imageView. I'm using Alpha_8 Configuration because it takes less memory and most suitable for edge results.
How can I preview the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ALPHA_8 format was made to be used as a mask because it only contains alpha and no color information. You should convert it to another format or if you want to use it anyway then you should put it as a mask for background for example. [Check out this response](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25796#c1) from an Android project member to a similar issue. You can also check out [my response to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37860845/2343817), there I put a code example about how to apply a mask to another bitmap.

Comment: So I understand that I cannot use Alpha_8 to save the edges on it. I'm obliged to use ARGB_8888?

Comment: You can use ARGB_8888 or ARGB_565, but you can always use your ALPHA_8 as a mask. You can't see it in your ImageView because it only contains alpha information and your ImageView doesn't have anything to apply to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ColorMatrixColorFilter` to display ALPHA_8 bitmap.
For example, use the following matrix

```
mColorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new float[]{
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255
});
```

to draw your bitmap using RED color.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    mPaint.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,x,y,mPaint);
}
```